# SwiftUI: Why doesn't this view get pinned to the bottom of its parent?

Tags: swiftui, layout, alignment

I'm a little late to the SwiftUI party.  I'm wondering why the following code results in the red rectangle being drawn at the center of the screen and not at the bottom.  I thought setting `alignment: bottom` would indicate it would like be aligned to the bottom of its parent (since I told the ZStack to have maxHeight/Width: .infinity)

So what am I missing here?

```
extension ContentView {
    @MainActor final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var showsToolbar = true
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                
                Button("Hello, world!") {
                    withAnimation {
                        viewModel.showsToolbar.toggle()
                    }
                }
                
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
            
            if viewModel.showsToolbar {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, idealHeight: 44, alignment: .bottom) // aren't I telling it to pin itself to the bottom of its parent here??
                    .frame(height: 44)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                    .animation(.default, value: viewModel.showsToolbar)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // fill the screen
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: The alignment needs to be on the ZStack, not the Rectangle. Try: ```ZStack(alignment: .bottom)```

Comment: That worked, thanks.  Unfortunately the view doesn't slide completely out of the view.  It slides to the edge of the safe area then is removed.

Comment: I noticed the same effect if I use the .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) to accomplish this red rectangle (future toolbar) functionality.

Comment: don't worry about the second bit; I found a solution for that.  It's a bit more involved involving a GeometryReader and some view preferences and a safe area insets binding.